# How to export tabulations

Tags: stata

I have a small project where I need to tabulate a dataset with frequencies in various ways and export those tables in a large Excel sheet. Unfortunately, copy and paste truncates text-labels and causes lots of other issues for us.

Is there a way to save/export the result into a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or Excel format?

That is, something similar to the `write.table` command in [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), which I can't install at work.

---

**Update 1:**

The Stata FAQ provided three solutions which would work for us: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/copying-tables/, but Stata support did a followup mail a shortly after pointing to the FAQ with a link to tabout and the tutorial displayed some truly beautiful tabulations.

[image: Table from the tutorial]

We've had some progress with the tabout, but we are not really sure if it would do everything we need, but so far creating tabulations with tabout D7 test.xls works nicely although without any proper aligment of labels and such as you would get generating [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

---

**Update 2:**

OK, so lots of tables weren't as straightforward as with tabulate and the by command in combination - some programming was required (not done at current Stata skill-level). The lack of native support for just exporting any result out is a real pain!

Answer (score 3):

`outreg` is not going to work, as it only works with estimation (regression-like) results. `xml_tab` can probably produce anything you like (`findit xml_tab` to install). Obviously, you can `export excel` your data, although if you need frequency tables, you probably would want to `collapse (count) ..., by(varlist)` your data first. (I hate `collapse` though, as I think it is a poor idea that you need to destroy and reload your data; this is one example where R's concept of objects comes handier than Stata's idea of having only one data set in memory at a time.)

Answer (score 3):

When wanting the tabulated output to anything, whether `tabulate` or `regress` or `clogit`, I always close the current `log` file and begin a new one, not in the `.smcl` format but with a `.log` suffix, handy because usually I want to keep a lot of the values from `clogit` returns

something along the lines of...

```
*close logs even if there isn't any
capture log close
log using NAMEOFOUTPUT.log
```

do something like `tab` or `reg` or `clogit`

```
log close
```

Your tabulated results from whichever command will then be in that `.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

Could outreg be a solution?
http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/rc/stata-outreg.htm

Since the above will only do regression tables, estout is a good alternative.  And the command estpost, I believe creates tables for tabulations:
http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html

Comment: Thanks, i haven't tried it yet because I'll have to figure out how to do it behind a firewall and in a citrix terminal-server enviroment :-) I found it via google earlier today, but I found it too strange to be true that tabulation was implemented as some sort of 'demo'-function in an application like Stata, hehe ;-D

Answer (score 0):

For one way frequency tables `fre` module can be quite handy too. Output can be written to tab-delimited table and LaTeX.

```
    sysuse auto, clear

    fre rep78

    rep78 -- Repair Record 1978
    -----------------------------------------------------------
                  |      Freq.    Percent      Valid       Cum.
    --------------+--------------------------------------------
    Valid   1     |          2       2.70       2.90       2.90
            2     |          8      10.81      11.59      14.49
            3     |         30      40.54      43.48      57.97
            4     |         18      24.32      26.09      84.06
            5     |         11      14.86      15.94     100.00
            Total |         69      93.24     100.00
    Missing .     |          5       6.76
    Total         |         74     100.00
    -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Download and more info on SSC:

http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456835.html